# change or add letter in text file -C++ QT

Tags: c++, qt, file

I`m working with text file,
and I want to read a text file line by line,
and if line start with # I want to write before it *
for example I have this file:

```
hello
world
#house
tree
```

I want it to be:

```
hello
world
*#house
tree
```

and if it easier I dont mind to do :
*house
or instead all the line to do that:

```
hello
world
*
tree
```

Do you know how to do it?
thank:)

Comment: what specific problem did you encounter? Do you know how to read a file? Do you know how to write a file?

Comment: why the `qt` tag? Are you using qt in your code? Can you show your code?

Comment: I am using QTI know to do everything- open- close

Comment: You can't add or remove characters arbitrarily in files, only at the end. The normal method is to read the entire file, modify the data, and then save all of it; or work line-by-line, saving each line to a new file, and then replace the old file with the new.

Comment: what that I dont know is how to change the line after I found line that begin with #

Comment: suppose you have a string: `std::string s = "#house";` do you know how to modify it ?

Comment: please show your code. Don't let us guess. Its not clear from the quesiton where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your replies:)
I understood that the best way is to Read the file line by line and write the modified version out into a new file. Then close and remove the old file and rename the new one.
have a nice day:)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).